# Authenticate Username and Password iOS

Tags: ios, sql, authentication

I have a website that users can log into to see their account info.

I would like to build functionality into my `iOS` app that allows them to log in and see their info in the app.  The usernames and passwords are stored in a `SQL` database.

How can I authenticate the **username and password** the user types into the app with the database?

Comment: What platform is your webserver?

Comment: IIS on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

Answer (score 0):

If you have better atuthentication system in your web..

then i would prefer you to use the `WEBVIEW` for your login page. and continues the other using the normal app flow.

Answer (score 0):

there are lot of tutorials for creating username and password login Function in IOS. i dont know whther you are basic or new progrmmer. But try this you may get some idea.
   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HrZR2SyeoSk.

You can go with JSON serialisation, if you experienced to load data from server.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can go about this but at the end of the day you need an endpoint for your iOS application to talk to your web server. This can be done with a TCP connection (little more complicated) or with a RESTful HTTP API endpoint which is generally the way most developers will go.

To get you running up and quickly on the client side have a look at [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com) to do the heavy lifting on your HTTP requests. You will then need a URL on your website that the iOS application can query. Abstract things to keep your API on a different subdomain, say for instance by creating a subdomain to handle your API requests. A login example could look like this

```
http://api.mysite.com/login
```

For a PHP based REST API here is a tutorial for you, [PHP API](http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/) or you could use a Node.js framework such as [Restify](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/)

The general practise is to use JSON encoded data when sending requests back and forth from the server, iOS 7 has built in JSON encoding/decoding, node and PHP also have pretty good support.

Once you are able to send and receive HTTP request from your iOS device to your web server it is just a matter of checking the username and password match up on the server side (seems you already know how to do this?) to the ones in your database and sending back a authentication BOOL and option error message if failed.